# Android: How to change the Summary of a PreferenceScreen programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a PreferenceScreen child element (containing the ZonePicker fragment) in the following .xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:title="@string/DateTimePreferencesTitle">
   <CheckBoxPreference android:key="cb_pref"
       android:title="@string/cb_pref_title"
       android:summaryOn="@string/summaryOn"
       android:summaryOff="@string/summaryOff"
       />
       .
       .
       .
   <PreferenceScreen
       android:fragment="com.trimble.ag.amaethon.preferences.ZonePicker"
       android:key="timezone"
       android:title="@string/date_time_set_timezone"
       android:summary="GMT-8:00"
       />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The ZonePicker fragment extends ListFragment.  I am trying to find a way to get at the above PreferenceScreen element and change the android:summary value from within the ZonePicker fragment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827356/setting-ui-preference-summary-field-to-the-value-of-the-preference

Comment: I did, but I don't believe you can use this from inside a ListFragment.  I think this is only viable from a PreferenceActivity.