# Android change the value of the checkbox preference from another checkbox

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences

I have a checkbox preference and I want to set it's value from another checkbox. Now I can get the value from the checkboxpreference and set it to the external checkbox but I didn't know how to set the preference value from that external checkbox.Any Help PleaseThis is my 
code

```
 getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());            musicpref = getPrefs.getBoolean("musicp", true);    
        CheckBox musiccheck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1); 
       //The external Checkbox, is checked will start service , if not will stop it
                musiccheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {

                            Intent musicstart = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                    ServiceMusic.class);
                            startService(musicstart);
                        } else {
                            Intent musicstart = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                                    ServiceMusic.class);
                            stopService(musicstart);
                        }

                    }
                });


                // Preference checkbox , if is true will set the external checkbox to true 
                if (musicpref == true) {
                    musiccheck.setChecked(true);
                }else{
                    musiccheck.setChecked(false);
                }
```

Comment: So you know how to get the checkBox preference but dont know how to set it correct ?

Comment: Yes exactly I didn't know how to set it from the external checkbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
SharedPreferences preferendecs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
Editor editor = preferencess.edit();
editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, musiccheck.getValue());
editor.commit();
```

You could also refer to this :

http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/08/example-of-using-checkboxpreference.html
and

[How do I capture changes of a CheckBoxPreference in android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260841/how-do-i-capture-changes-of-a-checkboxpreference-in-android-development)

Comment: Worked Very Well, Thanks +1 and Best answer