# Android List Preferences: have summary as selected value?

Tags: java, android

I have a Preference activity which uses a List Preferences as defined by my XML file. How would I set the summary of the list activity to the value that is selected?

Answer (score 429):

The simplest way to do this is just to have Android do it for you.  Assuming you want the summary to match the selected value, you can simply [set the summary of the `ListPreference` to `"%s"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#setSummary%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) using either XML or the `setSummary` method in Java.  For example:

```
<ListPreference
    android:key="pref_list"
    android:title="A list of preferences"
    android:summary="%s"
    android:entries="@array/pref_list_entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_list_entries_values"
    android:defaultValue="0" />
```

Android will replace `%s` with the current string value of the preference, as displayed by the `ListPreference`'s picker.  The list's summary will also be set correctly when you enter the activity—you don't have to write any special code to set it up initially.

This [also works](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/ListPreference.html#setSummary(java.lang.CharSequence)) with the AndroidX `ListPreference`.

I spent *far* too much time mucking with `SharedPreferences` listeners before I discovered this.

Comment: I know! I love those elegant solutions. So simple, yet hard to find ;)

Comment: +1 Very useful, clean, wise and fast solution because writing an extra source code for custom `PreferenceChangeListener` now seems like a waste of time. Many thanks budddy, you saved my day :)

Comment: I had to combine this wit manual updating... because summary is not updated when value is changed...

Comment: Excellent answer. Believe it or not but this is actually documented:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#setSummary(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Can you confirm, that you need API >= 11 for `"%s"` ? In my tests, `"%s"` doesn't work with Gingerbread and earlier versions.

Comment: Its not wirking with API < 11

Comment: This works like a charm. However, since I am setting the default value without any user interaction, there is no preference data saved. How do I retrieve the value from the Activity?

Comment: @si8 might want to ask a new question; not entirely sure what your problem is yet.

Comment: One note: it sets the value, not the label.

Comment: Works great with `androidx.preference`. Summary is updated accordingly.

Comment: @BaptisteCandellier thanks for the heads-up.  If something exists, the Android team will deprecate it.  I've added a link to `androidx`.

Answer (score 28):

You can use `OnPreferenceChangeListener` to dynamically change the summary. The problem is that it gets the selected value (from `android:entryValues`), not the caption (`android:entries`). In the following code I used `toString()`, but the proper solution is to find the caption for the value. Anyways, the idea works:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.your_prefs);

        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference("preference_key");
        if(listPreference.getValue()==null) {
            // to ensure we don't get a null value
            // set first value by default
            listPreference.setValueIndex(0);
        }
        listPreference.setSummary(listPreference.getValue().toString());
        listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                preference.setSummary(newValue.toString());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

I also wanted to achieve something similar, but the problem with https://stackoverflow.com/a/8155029/592025 is that, it shows the value for my preference (like 1, 2 3 etc). I want to show the entry (human readable string) corresponding to the selected value.

So I changed it this way and works the way I need it.

```
listPreference.setSummary(servicePreference.getEntry().toString());
listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            // Set the value as the new value
            listPreference.setValue(newValue.toString());
            // Get the entry which corresponds to the current value and set as summary
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntry());
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The trick is to use `getEntry()` instead of `getValue()` and once the value is changed, to set the value explicitly and read back the entry.

Answer (score 12):

So simple - just add the following property to your XML definition -

```xml
<ListPreference
...    
app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true"
...
/>
```

Comment: I think this should be upvoted as it seems like this is the preferred solution over %s. At least according to the message I get in logcat: "Setting a summary with a String formatting marker is no longer supported. You should use a SummaryProvider instead".

Answer (score 8):

I think that what you are looking for is much simple that you can think, add the following code line to your `Preference` item:

```
android:summary="%1$s"
```

So it will look something like this:

```
<ListPreference
            android:key="@string/pref_temp_key"
            android:title="@string/pref_temp_title"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_temp_dialog_title"
            android:entries="@array/pref_tempUnit_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_tempUnit_entries"
            android:summary="%1$s"
            android:defaultValue="@string/pref_temp_default_value" />
```

Answer (score 3):

First get a reference to the ListPreference in your onCreate.  You can use findPreference().  For example:

```
ListPreference pref = (ListPreference) findPreference("thePreferencesKey");
```

Then, when you first load the Activity and whenever the preferences value is changed, use whatever method you want to get the value of the ListPreference and set the summary with:

```
pref.setSummary(theNewString);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I'm using, it does not call setValue manually, as I believe this is already done at a later stage.

Here is an example:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value)
{
    String textValue = value.toString();

    ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
    int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(textValue);

    CharSequence[] entries = listPreference.getEntries();

    preference.setSummary(
                index >= 0
                        ? entries[index]
                        : null);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I did and it works great. In the **onSharedPreferenceChangeListener** I just check the key of what is getting changed and then for ListPreferences convert it back to the Human readable (entry instead of entryValue) with the if statements. Pretty simple.

```
public class MyPreferences extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    context = getActivity();

    if (context == null){
        Log.e("error","context is null");
    }

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    myFrequencyList = (Preference)  findPreference("frequency_key");
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {

        if(key.equals("frequency_key")){
                String freq = sharedPreferences.getString("frequency_key", "8k Hz");
                if(freq.equals("8000")){
                    freq = "8k Hz";
                }
                else if(freq.equals("16000")){
                    freq = "16k Hz";
                }
                else if(freq.equals("22050")){
                    freq = "22.05k Hz";
                }
                else if(freq.equals("44100")){
                    freq = "44.1k Hz";
                }
                else if(freq.equals("48000")){
                    freq = "48k Hz";
                }
                else{
                    freq = "8k Hz";
                }
                myFrequencyList.setSummary(freq);
        }
```

xml layout

```
 <ListPreference android:id="@+id/frequency_list"
        android:key="frequency_key"
        android:summary="8000"
        android:title="Sample Rate"
        android:defaultValue="8000"
        android:dialogTitle="Larger sample rates create better sound quality but larger file sizes."
        android:entries="@array/freq_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/freq_values"
        />
```

xml array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string-array name="freq_titles">
    <item>48k Hz</item>
    <item>44.1k Hz</item>
    <item>22.05k Hz</item>
    <item>16k Hz</item>
    <item>8k Hz</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="freq_values">
    <item>48000</item>
    <item>44100</item>
    <item>22050</item>
    <item>16000</item>
    <item>8000</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: Ideally you'd read the summary dynamically so you don't have to keep track of it in two places.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an expanded version of midhunhk's answer that addresses the helpful "android:summary" string as well

```
        // Retrieve & populate flash modes
        List<String> flashmodes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if (flashmodes != null) {
            final ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) findPreference("flash_list");
            final String lp_basesummary = "Set the Flash mode. The default is 'auto'";

            lp.setEntries(flashmodes.toArray(new CharSequence[flashmodes.size()]));
            lp.setEntryValues(flashmodes.toArray(new CharSequence[flashmodes.size()]));
            // If there's only one option, make it the default
            if (flashmodes.size() == 1)
                lp.setValueIndex(0);

            lp.setSummary(lp_basesummary + " [" + lp.getEntry() + "]");

            lp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    // Set the value as the new value
                    lp.setValue(newValue.toString());
                    // Get the entry which corresponds to the current value
                    // and set as summary
                    preference.setSummary(lp_basesummary + " [" + lp.getEntry() + "]");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Remove the preference
            ((PreferenceGroup) findPreference("camera_preference")).removePreference(findPreference("flash_list"));
        }

        // Retrieve & populate focus modes
        List<String> focusmodes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
        if (focusmodes != null) {
            final ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) findPreference("focus_mode_list");
            final String lp_basesummary = "Set the Focus mode. The default is 'auto'";
...
```

And, just to be clear, android:summary is removed from the related xml.

Answer (score 0):

And here's one way to deal with the Ringtone preference's summary update following a user selection.

```
    final SharedPreferences preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    final RingtonePreference rp_shuttle = (RingtonePreference) findPreference("shuttle_tone");
    rp_shuttle.setSummary(RingtoneManager
            .getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(preference.getString("shuttle_tone", "DEFAULT_SOUND")))
            .getTitle(this));

    rp_shuttle.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference mypreference, Object newValue) {
            rp_shuttle.setSummary(RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(newValue + ""))
                    .getTitle(getApplicationContext()));

            return true;
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You hava a method bindPreferenceSummaryToValue on your PreferenceActivity,

you can easily add the summary to the list doing like this:

```
private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

    sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}
```

On yout OnCreate method you call the bind function like this:

```
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.KEY_OF_THE_LIST)));
```

You can easily add others summary on the same way:

```
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.KEY_1)));
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.KEY_2)));
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.KEY_3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

under onCreatePreferences do this::

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
PreferenceScreen prefScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
int count = prefScreen.getPreferenceCount();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  Preference p = prefScreen.getPreference(i);
    if (p instanceof ListPreference) {
       String value = sharedPreferences.getString(p.getKey(), "");
       ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
       int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
       if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
      }
    }
 }
```