# Android EditTextPreference show value in summary

Tags: android

I would like to show the preference value in the summary field. This [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823442/android-list-preferences-have-summary-as-selected-value) shows how to do it for a `ListPreference`.

Is there a similar way to do it for an `EditTextPrefernce` in the layout instead of extending the class?

Comment: I am assuming you have tried this and it doesn't work? The docs make it seem like it should work since this class inherits Preference functionality http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setSummary(int) or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#attr_android:summary

Answer (score 1):

I just have a little method that updates the preference summary every time a preference changes. I found this somewhere online back when I needed it but unfortunately I don't remember where to credit :(

Edit: Nevermind, I found the source.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4325239/3238938