# Non Deprecated findPreference() Method? - Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, deprecated, android-preferences

I want to detect when a `Preference` contained in a `ListView` gets clicked, so that I can launch an intent to manage that selection.

I would have done like this in my layout `XML` file:

```
<Preference android:title="About" android:key="myKey"></Preference>
```

And the following in my `java` code:

```
Preference myPref = (Preference) findPreference("myKey");
myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
             public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                 //open browser or intent here
             }
         });
```

But the method [`public Preference findPreference (CharSequence key)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html#findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) is deprecated.

1. Is there a non deprecated equivalent?
2. If not, what if I use it anyway?
3. How can `Fragments` help me do my task in a better way? Check here: [Preferences without deprecated methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503496/preferences-without-deprecated-methods).

---

Here you can check the `XML` layout structure that my activity has, and a snapshot of the application:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Preference
        android:key="about"
        android:title="@string/titleAbout"
        android:summary="@string/summaryAbout"
    />

    <Preference
        android:key="labelTaxonomy"
        android:title="@string/titleLabelTaxonomy"
        android:summary="@string/summaryLabelTaxonomy"
    />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**SNAPSHOT:**

[image: snapshopt]

After clicking on the About (or Access Label Taxonomy) `Preference`, I'd like to open an `intent` of some kind (could also be a video or anything else...the names are misleading).

Comment: I have a problem similar to yours. I do a bunch of things in Preferences (that probably I shouldn't), and I do need `findPreference()` to do some java on clicks. Not sure how to handle this now without heavily changing the whole thing, or ignoring the deprecation. :/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> Is there a non deprecated equivalent?

If you are using `PreferenceFragment` on API Level 11+ devices, you would call `findPreference()` on it. Otherwise, call `findPreference()` on your `PreferenceActivity`, as you have no choice.

> If not, what if I use it anyway?

It will work.

> How can Fragments help me do my task in a better way?

API Level 11+ introduced `PreferenceFragment` as another way of constructing the contents of a `PreferenceActivity`. You are welcome to use them, but if you are still supporting older devices, you cannot use `PreferenceFragment` for those devices.

That being said:

> I want to detect when a Preference contained in a ListView gets clicked, so that I can launch an intent to manage that selection.

You do not need Java code for this. Use:

```
    <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/title_intent_preference"
            android:summary="@string/summary_intent_preference">

        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:data="http://www.android.com" />

    </PreferenceScreen>
```

(as seen in the [JavaDocs for `PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html))

This will create an entry in the preference UI that, when clicked, will start an activity with the specified `Intent`.

Comment: Thks a lot, just two other questions: 1) I have many preferences entries <Preference> inside of my <PreferenceScreen>, can I still use the `XML` approach you are suggesting in the snippet just for one single `Preference` entry?and how? 2) Suppose I want to use a new `intent`, I'm forced to used some java code to create it, correct? I hope you can help me, Thks again! ;D

Comment: @Matteo: 1) Read the JavaDocs that I linked to, and see the example of the use of this `<intent>` approach in and among other preferences. 2) I have no idea what "a new `intent`" means in this case.

Comment: 1) Thks... 2) Let me explain better: it seemed to me that the intent described in your `XML` snippet is only for visiting a website by opening the browser. Suppose I want to launch an intent opening another activity, or displaying a video from the gallery of the phone, or anything else, I should define the new intent in the standard Java way, correct?

Comment: @Matteo: IMHO, preferences should not be leading to random places. Preferences are for *preferences*, not for displaying videos. The purpose of `<intent>` is if you have something that logically is part of the app's settings but cannot readily be rendered using the standard preference UI. That being said, if your `Intent` is not static, you will need to handle it via Java, probably using code along the lines of what you have in your question.

Comment: I c...!So I should not use `Preferences` in the way I'm doing?(You can check the added part of the question)...If not what kind of class should I use instead?Thks so much for you help, and sorry if it's a stupid question, I'm a beginner in android... ;D

Comment: @Matteo: I would just have "About" be in your options menu or the overflow menu of the action bar.

Comment: And what class should I use instead for the other entries? a `ListActivity`?

Comment: @Matteo: Since I don't know what "Access Label Taxonomy" is supposed to do, I cannot answer that question, sorry.

Comment: It should launch an intent visualising a video, or opening the browser, or anything like that. Thks for your help, really!

Answer (score 5):

If you use fragments, you can use the method "findPreference()" on the basis of a preferences fragment.

```
public class CustomActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom);

      CustomFragment customFragment = (CustomFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.custom_fragment);
      EditTextPreference textPreference = (EditTextPreference) customFragment.findPreference("preference_key");

      textPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
         public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
             //open browser or intent here
         }
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: So what is the `R.id.custom_fragment`? I am trying to get the preference from within my custom fragment and can't figure it.

Comment: The `R.id.custom_fragment` is the id of your defined fragment. For example: `<fragment
android:id="@+id/custom_fragment"
android:name="com.example.CustomFragment"/>`

Answer (score 2):

**2018 UPDATE**
Today, the `onPreferenceTreeClick` method has to be overriden in the Preference fragment for this purpose. For example:

```
public class MySettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick (PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
                                          Preference preference)
    {
        String key = preference.getKey();
        if(key.equals("someKey")){
            // do your work
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Deprecated in API 15

Answer (score 1):

maybe [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) link are  not clear. But using that feature is very simple. for example, you can use that as a twitter  page like this

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Share" >
 <PreferenceScreen
        android:title="Twitter"
        android:summary="Follow me at Twitter">

    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:data="https://twitter.com/" />

</PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

it doesnt need any java code. Thanks to CommonsWare!