# Android: Preference button clicked?

Tags: android, button, dialog, sharedpreferences, preferences

I have a shared preference screen with check box's list preferences etc. Now I would like to add a button in the shared preference screen that when I click it a dialog pops up. I do this and it looks perfect to make the button on the preference screen:

```
<Preference
        android:key="key"
        android:summary="make pop up dialog"
        android:title="dialog" />
```

But now I don't know how to get when it is clicked I tried and I cant use onSharedPreferenceChanged because no preferences are changed its just clicked. So what would I do to get when the preference button is clicked? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272839/non-deprecated-findpreference-method-android/23081464#23081464

Answer (score 6):

First, your `PreferenceActivity` must implement `Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener`.
Then, under the `onCreate` function call

`findPreference(YOUR_KEY_PREF).setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);`

and add this function

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    String key = preference.getKey();
    if(key.equals(YOUR_KEY_PREF)){
        showYourDialog();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your case, `YOUR_KEY_PREF` is `"key"`