# How do we dynamically add an array from a java file to an existing xml file in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, resources, preferences

We are trying to dynamically add an array in a java file to a xml file.

We have an ArrayList catList which is filled by reading a xml file from a website. The ArrayList is filled like this: [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5].

preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListPreference
    android:title="Ondernemer selecteren"
    android:summary="Bij deze optie kunt U kiezen van welke ondernemer U de agenda wilt zien."
    android:key="listPref"
    android:defaultValue="Standaard"
    android:entries="@array/ondernemerArray"
    android:entryValues="@array/ondernemerValues"
/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>    
 <string-array name="ondernemerArray">
    <item></item>
</string-array>

 <string-array name="ondernemerValues">
    <item></item>
</string-array>
```

Does anyone know how we can put the catList array dynamically into the xml file, between the  elements and dynamically increase the amount of  elements?

Comment: You can't change `resources` at runtime. Once they are compiled, that's it. You will need to store them in some form of [persistent storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 1):

To fill a preference list with dynamic values you create the preference in settings.xml but do not specify its android:entries and android:entryValues properties.

```
<ListPreference 
    android:title="@string/pref_title"
    android:summary="@string/pref_summary"
    android:key="prefkey"
    android:defaultValue="" />
```

Then you add some code in your preferences activity onCreate to fill the entries and entryValues from your xml data.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    initializePreferenceList();

    ...
}

protected void initializePreferenceList(){

    ListPreference lpPref = (ListPreference)findPreference("prefkey");

    // Read your xml data somehow
    ...

    // Write some methods to fill a String array from your xml data:
    // something like toEntriesArray, toEntryValuesArray
    String[] entries = toEntriesArray(xmlData);
    String[] entryValues = toEntryValuesArray(xmlData);

    lpPref.setEntries(entries);
    lpPref.setEntryValues(entryValues);
}
```

You don't need to define any values in array.xml for this preference.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. But we still can't get it working because eclipse gives an error at "findPrefence" and "addPreferencesFromResource". Do you know how we can fix that?

Comment: @Geert, I checked versions, the method android.preference.PreferenceActivity.findPreference was deprecated in API level 11. I should have included my Android version in the response, sorry. I found this response about using the non-deprecated PreferenceFragment.findPreference method on API Level 11+ devices: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11273826/1182515)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, `resources` can't be changed after they are compiled. So when you have things that need to be updated during runtime, such as an `Array` here, you will need to use one of the several forms of [persistent storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) available. Which one to use will depend on your data and your needs. If you don't need it to be persistent then you can use a `static array` but it doesn't sound like that's what you need here.

The `resources` mostly help keep from cluttering up your java code and aren't meant to be dynamic but more to make things easier for the developer as far as a place to store and reference things pre-compile. I know this isn't the answer you were looking for but hopefully that can help clear things up a bit about `resources`.

If anyone has a better or more accurate description to add, feel free to edit