# How to send the value of radio button in server using json?

Tags: android, json, radio-button

In my application I am trying to send data to server, data is sending properly and I am getting successful message from response,but I dont know how to send value of radio button,because in server data is not storing,see my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311273/how-to-find-value-of-radio-button-same-like-html

```
public class Filter extends Activity{

private TextView sp;
private EditText tv;
private ImageView b;
private TextView sp1;
private TextView agefrom;
private TextView ageto;
private RadioGroup rdgrp;
private RadioButton rdall;
private RadioButton rdfilter;
private LinearLayout linfirst;
private LinearLayout linsecond;
private TextView spmrg;
static Dialog d ;
String USERLOGINID;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private ImageView saves;
private static final String FILTER_URL = "";
private static final String FILTER_SUCCESS = "status";
private static final String FILTER_LOGIN = "msg";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.filter);
    USERLOGINID=this.getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
    System.out.println("Filter"+USERLOGINID);
    sp=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinnerfilterdetailmothertong);
    sp1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinnerfilterdetaicountry);
    spmrg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinnerfiltermarrage);
    agefrom=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinneragefilterfrom);
    ageto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.spinneragefilterto);
    rdgrp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGender);
    rdall=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.allowall);
    rdfilter=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.allowfilter);
    linfirst=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayoutfilter);
    linsecond=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearsecondpart);
    saves=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
    linfirst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    linsecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    rdgrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id=rdgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
              View radioButton = rdgrp.findViewById(id);
              if(radioButton.getId()==R.id.allowall)
              {
                  linfirst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                linsecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
              else
              {
                  linfirst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                linsecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }
        }
    });

    final String[] mrgstatus = new String[] {"Married", "Never Married", "Divorced","Seperated","Widow/Widower"};
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptermrgstatus = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Filter.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mrgstatus);
    spmrg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View w) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(Filter.this)
              .setTitle("Select")
              .setAdapter(adaptermrgstatus, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    spmrg.setText(adaptermrgstatus.getItem(which).toString());

                  dialog.dismiss();
                }
              }).create().show();
            }
    });

    final String[] country = new String[] {"Afganistan", "Albania", "Algeria","India","Pakistan"};
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adaptercountry = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Filter.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, country);
    sp1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View w) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(Filter.this)
              .setTitle("Select")
              .setAdapter(adaptercountry, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    sp1.setText(adaptercountry.getItem(which).toString());

                  dialog.dismiss();
                }
              }).create().show();
            }
    });

    final String[] langs = new String[] {"Afganistan", "Albania", "Algeria","India","Pakistan"};
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterlangs = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Filter.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, langs);
    sp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View w) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(Filter.this)
              .setTitle("Select")
              .setAdapter(adapterlangs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    sp.setText(adapterlangs.getItem(which).toString());

                  dialog.dismiss();
                }
              }).create().show();
            }
    });

    final String[] catagory = new String[] {"18", "19", "20","21","22", "23","24","25","26","27", "28","29","30","31","32", "33","34","35","36","37", "38","39","40","41","42", "43","44","45","46","47", "48","49","50","51","52", "53","54","55","56","57", "58","59","60","61","62", "63","64","65","66","67", "68","69","70"};
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapteragefrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Filter.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, catagory);
    agefrom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View w) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(Filter.this)
              .setTitle("Select")
              .setAdapter(adapteragefrom, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    agefrom.setText(adapteragefrom.getItem(which).toString());

                  dialog.dismiss();
                }
              }).create().show();
            }
    });
    final String[] agetoo = new String[] {"18", "19", "20","21","22", "23","24","25","26","27", "28","29","30","31","32", "33","34","35","36","37", "38","39","40","41","42", "43","44","45","46","47", "48","49","50","51","52", "53","54","55","56","57", "58","59","60","61","62", "63","64","65","66","67", "68","69","70"};
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterageto = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Filter.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, agetoo);
    ageto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View w) {
              new AlertDialog.Builder(Filter.this)
              .setTitle("Select")
              .setAdapter(adapterageto, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    ageto.setText(adapterageto.getItem(which).toString());

                  dialog.dismiss();
                }
              }).create().show();
            }
    });
    saves.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
            rdall.setChecked(true);
        }
    });

}
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    boolean failure = false;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Filter.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Processing..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        //Check for success tag
        //int success;
        Looper.prepare();
        String userloginid=USERLOGINID.toString();
        String allowall=rdall.toString();
        String mothertongue = sp.getText().toString();
        String marital=spmrg.getText().toString();
        String agefroms=agefrom.getText().toString();
        String agetos=ageto.getText().toString();
        String contry=sp1.getText().toString();
         try {
             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_login_id", userloginid));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("all_allow", allowall));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("moth_tong", mothertongue));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("maritalstatus", marital));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age_from", agefroms));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age_to", agetos));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", contry));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("version", "apps"));

             Log.d("request!", "starting");
             // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
                 FILTER_URL, "POST", params);
             //check your log for json response
             Log.d("Request attempt", json.toString());
             final String str = json.toString();
             JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
             final String msg = jobj.getString("msg");
             System.out.println("MSG : " + msg);
             runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() 
             {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
            });

             return json.getString(FILTER_SUCCESS);

         }catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
    }

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //dismiss the dialog once product deleted
         pDialog.dismiss();
}}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27275090/1576416

this link may be your answer.

Comment: read question carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first store the value of radio button in a variable when it is selected or by using setOnCheckedChangeListener. 
use this answer [Android getting value from selected radiobutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179124/android-getting-value-from-selected-radiobutton)

then use that variable in your async task to get the text from it.

Comment: can you explain what is value in radio button?

Comment: if you want value then it can be text or choice made by user.

Comment: what do you mean by choice?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get the selected id in your asynctask doInBackground

```
int id=rdgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

right after

```
String contry=sp1.getText().toString();
```

then add the result in the parameters, something like that:

```
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("choice", id+""));
```

You can also define a global variable in your activity that the Asynctask can access.