# Is there a way to display the current setting of a PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I feel like I must be missing something, but I just don't see what it is... I have a `PreferenceActivity` with a bunch of various preferences (some are lists, some are just text fields) and it all works fine, but unless I explicitly write each item's value to the summary (which is obviously not intended for this purpose) I don't see how (or where) the items display what they are currently set to.  When I click on them the various views show up with the correct settings, but that's clearly not the intention.

Do I have to create my own custom List item of some sort that has a field that displays the currently populated value of each element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display the current value of an Android Preference in the Preference summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531427/how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-su)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the default PreferencesActivity doesn't display the values: what you're doing is really the way to go if you care to have all the preferences displayed *at a glance*.

Comment: I had a feeling that that was the case, but it's just bizarre that they would include such a useless mechanism... What's the point? It's not connected to my default shared preferences, right? So, it's not even a short cut to setting those (initially I thought maybe it was and the key field was used to look up my shared prefs, but that doesn't appear to be the case).  So... it's just a List view that holds on to its own values? I MUST be missing something!

Comment: Well, it is actually connected to your default shared preferences, so unless you're making a mistake elsewhere that SHOULD work. If you add an `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);` call in the `onCreate()` method it will pull those up. This assumes your XML preferences file is called *prefs.xml* in the *res/xml* folder.

Comment: interesting... I had a different name for my xml file... I'll see if that addresses the disparity.

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to go down the programming direction then look at this thread: [How do I display the current value of an Android Preference in the Preference summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531427/how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-sum)

Has everything there.

Answer (score 1):

Create another preference field: summary.
Update it whenever a preference field is updated, or when displaying the preferences screen.
The user will be able to "update" the summary value, but whenever he/she enters preferences, the correct value will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

For `ListPreferences`, this is built-in and you can use

```
android:summary="Actual value: %s"
```

For `EditTextPreferences`, you can [easily create your own class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25083261/1587329):

> ```
> package your.package.preference;
>
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.util.AttributeSet;
>
> public class EditTextPreference extends android.preference.EditTextPreference{
>         public EditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
>             super(context, attrs, defStyle);
>         }
>
>         public EditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>             super(context, attrs);
>         }
>
>         public EditTextPreference(Context context) {
>             super(context);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public CharSequence getSummary() {
>             String summary = super.getSummary().toString();
>             return String.format(summary, getText());
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> And use this in your xml:
>
> ```
> <your.package.EditTextPreference
>                 android:key="pref_alpha"
>                 android:summary="Actual value: %s"
>                 android:title="Title"
>                 android:defaultValue="default"
>                 />
> ```