# how to update EditTextPreference existing summary when i click ok button

Tags: android

I am able to show EditTextPreference with default summary. Now i want to update it when i enter new value in  Edit Text box and click ok then it should be upadate the value of summary. But i am unable to do that. My code is below please update in my code which required.

```java
public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

    final EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("username");
    pref.setSummary(pref.getText());
    pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
      public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        final EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("username");

        pref.setSummary(pref.getText());

        return true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

xml file is

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <EditTextPreference 
    android:title="User Name"
    android:key="username" 
    android:summary="Please provide user name" />
  <EditTextPreference 
    android:title="Password" 
    android:password="true"
    android:key="password" 
    android:summary="Please enter your password" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

actually my code update previous enter value as summary text. How to show text as summary when I click ok button. Thanks

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your preference activity doesn't appear to be implementing `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`

You may want to read over the excellent answer to the question:
[How do I display the current value of an Android Preference in the Preference summary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531427/how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-sum)

Answer (score 14):

You can implement this simply by subclassing `EditTextPreference` and overriding `getSummary()`.

```
package com.example.yourapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class FriendlyEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {

    public FriendlyEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public FriendlyEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FriendlyEditTextPreference(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    // According to ListPreference implementation
    @Override
    public CharSequence getSummary() {
        String text = getText();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            CharSequence hint = getEditText().getHint();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(hint)) {
                return hint;
            } else {
                return super.getSummary();
            }
        } else {
            CharSequence summary = super.getSummary();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(summary)) {
                return String.format(summary.toString(), text);
            } else {
                return summary;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your xml, replace `EditTextPreference` with `com.example.yourapplication.FriendlyEditTextPreference`

Now you can use string containing "%s" or "%1$s" as `android:summary` and it will update automatically; moreover, you can set `andorid:hint` so that the hint is also displayed when text is empty.

For A working `ListPreference` on all platforms, see my [answer of this uestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119852/listpreferences-summary-text-is-not-updated-automatically-whenever-there-is-cha/21642401#21642401)

Comment: Is %s supposed to work w/ EditTextPreference?  I could not get it to work.

Comment: @Iostintranslation %s is supposed to work with ListPreferencce in framework, but with the customization above, you can use it with EditTextPreference.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `newVal` (`preference.getText()` will return the previous value as it's not yet updated)

It should look somthing like this:

```
pref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        preference.setSummary((String)newValue); // TODO validate value
        return true;
    }
});
```