# Android preference activity does not update correctly

Tags: android, android-preferences

I created an android preference page and wanted to show the current option selected in the summary.

So I implemented the onSharedPreferenceChanged listener which is also called correctly. However, there is no screen change and the old option is shown.

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    // just update all
    ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) findPreference(PREF_DOWNLOAD_WEB);
    lp.setSummary(getString(R.string.pref_listDownloadWebSummary)  + ": %s");
}
```

Is this a known bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the updated summary is shown when I set another prefs summary. So I set the summary to "dummy" first and then the real string. It works too.

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    // just update all
    ListPreference lp = (ListPreference) findPreference(PREF_DOWNLOAD_WEB);
    lp.setSummary("dummy"); // required or will not update
    lp.setSummary(getString(R.string.pref_listDownloadWebSummary)  + ": %s");

}
```

Comment: What versions of Android have you tried that on? %s doesn't seem to work on Android 2.3. (I didn't try exactly the same code, but something very similar.)

Comment: This works fine on Android 2.3. Better if you post your code in a question.

Comment: Well I'm using a Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener instead, but I'm not sure it's really question worthy as it's pretty easy to just look up the string using findIndexOfValue.