# Get value from CheckBoxPreference when it is changed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create Preference Screen with a Checkbox control.

```
 <CheckBoxPreference android:summaryOn="@string/mySummaryOn" 
  android:summaryOff="@string/mySummaryOff" 
  android:key="myCB" 
  android:title="my checkbox"/>
```

I want to get this Boolean value when ever its getting changed.

In my Application i have done as below implementing OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

```
public boolean cbValue;
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
        prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //FacebookStatus=prefs.getBoolean("myCB", true);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Shared Preference Changes ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
```

onSharedPreferenceChanged method is not at all called even when i toggle check box in pref screen.

If i need to get value from Shared preference each time when value is changed wat should i do?

Comment: I have solved this by  [Shared Preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531427/how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-su) .... Thanks a lot guys for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`:

Add to your preference activity's `onCreate` method following line: `Preference myCheckbox = findPreference("myCB")`
Then apply a listener to `myCheckbox` object: `myCheckbox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(myCheckboxListener)`

Code of the listener (as a class field):

```
private OnPreferenceChangeListener myCheckboxListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // Read new value from Object newValue here
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Antek.... But myCheckbox.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(myCheckboxListener) it says myCheckboxListener cannpt be resolved... 

Do i need to implement any?

Comment: Hey Antek.... could you say how to get boolean value from Checkbox insidde onPreferenceClick???????????

Comment: Hey Antek I have solved this by  [Shared Preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531427/how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-su) .... Thanks a lot guys for help

Answer (score 1):

```
SwitchPreference switchPref = (SwitchPreference)findPreference("switchPref");
switchPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        boolean beforeChange = ((SwitchPreference) preference).isChecked();
        boolean afterChange = !beforeChange;
        ((SwitchPreference) preference).setChecked(afterChange);
        // Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+afterChange, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you override onPreferenceChange(), the checked status doesn't change when you clicked the switch.

Don't forget to add `switchPref.setChecked(!isChecked()).`

Answer (score 0):

You can read the new value directly with the `SharedPreferences` parameter object. If you know that the key is from the `CheckBoxPreference` you can just read the value:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    if (key == getString(R.string.CheckBoxKeyId)) {
        boolean myBool = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

This saves you adding an `OnPreferenceChangeListener` for each of the `CheckBoxPreference` you might have.