# How to iterate through all keys of shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

SharedPreferences have method getAll, but it returns no entries despite the fact some keys exist:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).contains("addNewAddress");
```

returns true

```
Map<String, ?> keys=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getAll();
```

returns empty map

What is wrong? How to get list of all shared preferences?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

What you can do is use [`getAll()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29) method of `SharedPreferences` and get all the values in `Map<String,?>` and then you can easily iterate through.

```
Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();

for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
            Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " + 
                                   entry.getValue().toString());            
 }
```

For more you can check [`PrefUtil.java's`](http://code.google.com/p/phxandroid/source/browse/trunk/phxandroid-sharedprefs-one/src/org/phxandroid/sharedprefs/PrefUtil.java?r=8) `dump()` implementation.

Comment: this is returning no values for me :(

Comment: `getAll()` can return `NULL` value. It would be better to check `keys` for NULL.

Comment: It's better use ``entry.getValue()`` rather than ``entry.getValue().toString()`` not to get NullPointerException)

Answer (score 9):

i think the question has more to do with why

```
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getAll()
```

is returning an empty/contradictory map than with how to iterate over a standard java map. the [android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#setDefaultValues%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20boolean%29) isn't really crystal clear about what's going here but basically it seems like the **first call ever** to

```
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences,false)
```

-- which is what you're supposed to call to initialize preferences when you start your app -- creates some kind of cached version of your preferences which causes future changes to your xml preferences file to be inconsistently handled, i.e., causing the mismatch you described in your question.

to reset this "cached entity", follow these steps (which you can sort of come up with from the above link):

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().clear();
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true);
```

Comment: the solution I needed was a combination of this answer and http://stackoverflow.com/a/9310697/1815624

Answer (score 4):

incase anyone wants to iterate through sharedpreferences in KOTLIN

```
 sharedPreferences?.all?.forEach {
     //access key using it.key & value using it.value
     Log.d("Preferences values",it.key() + ": " + it.value()             
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin is very easey, you can change FILE_PREF_XML for you preferences file

```kotlin
getSharedPreferences("FILE_PREF_XML", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).all?.forEach {
    Log.d(TAG,"shared pref(" + it.key + ") = " + it.value)
}
```