# how to know how many shared preference in shared preferences in android

Tags: android

I want to know how many shared preference in my shared preferences which are found in the file explorer by coding , is there any method to return the total number of shared preferences ?

[image]

Comment: how many entries the sharedpreferences contain? sharedPreferencesInstance.getAll().size()

Comment: this is what I want to know by coding if possible

Comment: I already give you a solution in my privious comment

Comment: @blackbelt: how to get the name of each pref plz ?

Comment: what does "name of each pref plz" mean ?

Comment: the name of each xml file exists in shared_prefs folder

Comment: how many files do you create. getSharedPreferences("yourname") create a new file . prefs.putString("key", "value"); put samething inside the file named yourname. What do you want ? A list of all the entris inside yourname.xml?

Comment: look at the picture which I've added to the post please .. I want to know the name of each entry in the shared preferences by coding

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the number of entries you can use

```
sharedPreferencesInstance.getAll().size()
```

To retrieve all the keys you stored previously you can use `keySet()`, as shown in the following snippet:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myshared", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Map<String,?> entries = prefs.getAll();
Set<String> keys = entries.keySet();
for (String key : keys) {

}
```

Answer (score 8):

In your activity try this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("your.package", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int howMany = prefs.getAll().size();
```

Comment: how to get the name of each pref plz ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are looking to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310697/976367) . If it is just the size then you can just do a

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(<NAME>, <MODE>);
pref.getAll().size();
```