# check if sharedpreferences key contains a constant

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Since i didn't find anything usefull, or something that reply at my question i would like to know if it's possible to check if a sharedpreference key contains a constant string.

Ex.

Stored on my shared prefs:

```
<string name="aaa_key1">Value</string>
<string name="aaa_key2">Value</string>
<string name="aaa_key3">Value</string>
<string name="bbb_key1">Value</string>
<string name="bbb_key2">Value</string>
<string name="bbb_key3">Value</string>
```

I need to add a check so:
if prefs contains aaa: do something,
if prefs contains bbb: do something else.

Edit for explain:
I got some methods on my app that generate sharedpreferences keys+strings based on Users action. All the keys got a constant based on the action executed by the users, so that i need to call some other methods if the keys contains the constant (i.e aaa_key1 or bbb_key1)

Is that possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are refering to sharedpreferences the wrong way. you could refer to this as a sample code: https://github.com/rakeeb11/simple-shared-preferences ... its always easier when you set sharedpreference in a separate class.

Comment: Nono, i'm refering it right... i got some method on my app that store sharedprefrences based on strings generated from users action. These strings got a constant at first so that i need to check if the strings stored got this constant and execute some other methods

Comment: when saving to sharedpreferences haven't you used any keys to identify them values? Because with sharedpreferences you ought to assign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find this helpful,to get a list of keys use following method.

What you can do is use getAll() method of SharedPreferences and
get all the values in Map and then you can easily iterate through.

```
   Map<String,?> keys = prefs.getAll();

    for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
                Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " + 
                                       entry.getValue().toString());   
       }
```

For more info check this original post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310479/how-to-iterate-through-all-keys-of-shared-preferences)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want separate values no need to get them all -  the correct answer in this case is [`prefs.contains(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29)

```
if (prefs.contains("aaa")
    // aaa
else if (prefs.contains("bbb")
    // bbb
```