# SharedPreferences without values

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences

That is how I save values in SharedPreferences:

```
private void GuardarConfiguracionEnXML() {
        SharedPreferences prefs =getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("ConfirmarPromocion", VarGlobales.ConfirmarPromocion);
        editor.putBoolean("NoPermitirCero", VarGlobales.NoPermitirCero);
        editor.putBoolean("ProponerCantidad", VarGlobales.ProponerCantidad);
        editor.putBoolean("ArticuloCodNum", VarGlobales.ArticuloCodNum);
        editor.putBoolean("GuardarRutas", VarGlobales.GuardarRutas);
        editor.putBoolean("IncluyeFabricante", VarGlobales.IncluyeFabricante);
        editor.putBoolean("CompararComienzo", VarGlobales.CompararComienzo);
        editor.putString("CadenaBusquedaArticulos", VarGlobales.CadenaBusquedaArticulos);
        editor.putString("SerieConfiguracion", VarGlobales.SerieConfiguracion);
        editor.putBoolean("MostrarPoblacion", VarGlobales.MostrarPoblacion);
        editor.putBoolean("RecogidaEnvases", VarGlobales.Recogidaenvases);
        editor.putBoolean("ConvertirACajas", VarGlobales.ConvertirACajas);
        editor.putBoolean("RepartoFinSemana", VarGlobales.RepartoFinSemana);
        if(VarGlobales.ModoBusArticulos == BuscarPorArticulo.CODIGO)
            editor.putInt("BusquedaDefectoArticulos", 3);
        else if(VarGlobales.ModoBusArticulos == BuscarPorArticulo.DESCRIPCIONC)
            editor.putInt("BusquedaDefectoArticulos", 1);
        else
            editor.putInt("BusquedaDefectoArticulos", 2);
        editor.putInt("DiasDiurno", VarGlobales.DiasDiurno);
        editor.putInt("DiasNocturno", VarGlobales.DiasNocturno);
        //editor.putBoolean("VentaSoloUnidades", VarGlobales.VentaSoloUnidades);
        editor.commit();

        Map<String, ?> testshared = prefs.getAll();
    }
```

`testshared` has all values, but when I start my apk i get 0 values:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Map<String, ?> testshared2 = prefs.getAll();
```

`testshared2`is empty... Why?

**EDIT: Was an Eclipse bug, I've rebooted my computer and now it works... Thanks to everybody.**

Comment: Do you call GuardarConfiguracionEnXML when you are in onPause?

Comment: GuardarConfiguracionEnXML is called in an OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

change

```
SharedPreferences prefs =getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

To this

```
SharedPreferences prefs =getSharedPreferences("MisPreferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
```

Comment: "prefs cannot be resolved to a type", it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry about that.  What you have actually works with my code.  Could you supply more code to help with the context?

Answer (score 0):

Your "put/commit" code looks correct to me.

However, there are some pitfalls with getAll :

[How to iterate through all keys of shared preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310479/how-to-iterate-through-all-keys-of-shared-preferences)

I suggest you try retrieving an individual value (e.g. using getBoolean or getString) to determine whether this is the problem.

Comment: I've used getAll while I was debugging, I just was using this to know which values had my sharedpreferences file. Was an Eclipse bug, I've rebooted my computer and now it works...

Comment: The point I was making was that the getAll looked suspect and my suggestion was to use getBoolean or getString instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use sharedPreferences based on my activities. You can use "getApplicationContext()" if you are out of activity or fragment class, you can use "getActivity()" in fragment class or "this" in activity class.

To put data:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
refsEditor.putString(Key1, Value1);
refsEditor.putString(Key2, Value2);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

to retrieve data:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
String str = prefs.getString(Key1, "defValue");
```