# What I missing when tried to retrieve data from Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, sharedpreferences

Hey guyz check it out what I am missing here cause of I am not able to fetch all my data from Shared Preferences.
I am making such an tasklist application in which I am saving my data(means mytask) with a certain key and storing it in the shared Preferences and increments a variable for total count.

Check my Code(Whenever I click on addTask button the following code gets executed).

```
private void saveToSharedPreference(){
    sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("todoPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPre.edit();
    String myKey = "key"+a;
    String myValue = et.getText().toString();
    editor.putString(myKey,myValue);
//        editor.putInt("totalTask", a);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Now when I close the application and open it again the following code gets executed in order to load the data from shared preferences.

```
private  void loadData(){
    sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("todoPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int p = 1;
    String myKey = "key"+p;
    while(sharedPre.getString(myKey,"") != null){
        Toast.makeText(this, sharedPre.getString(myKey,""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

but the problem is all it always returning null on all indexes. I don't know why I am getting this error. Please help me
Thanks in advance
Sarosh Madara

Comment: What's the value of `a` in `String myKey = "key"+a;`?

Comment: In `String myKey = "key"+a;`. What value has `a`? And what type is it?  Try to name your variables appropriately. Nobody else knows what `a` might be.

Comment: Are the values same for a & p variables???

Comment: You save and load **different key names** (i.e.: you save "key0" and you load "key1"). If there is no 100% match, you won't retrieve the saved key.

Comment: Why do u want a while loop if key is same, that is ur not incrementing the index(p) in while or are u trying to create an infinite loop....

Comment: sorry jofre and gainttree the a is an int var which always increments... 1

Comment: Yes clairvoyant both are same... for the time being if I input 3 values key1 key2 and key3 then I want to retrieve key1 key2 and key3 thats why they would definitely be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to load all saved values just use the following code:

```
private void loadData() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("todoPref",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Map<String,?> keys = sharedPre.getAll();
        for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
                if (entry.getValue().toString().length() > 0) {
                    Log.d("map values",entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());     
                }
         }
    }
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310697/1709850) but added a check to ignore null values.

to save values to Shared Preference I suggest using an instance of the current time for the key. no need to save any integer key values:

```
private void saveToSharedPreference(String myValue){
        SharedPreferences sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("todoPref",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedPre.edit();
        String key = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        editor.putString(key,myValue);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

so whenever you want to add values to Shared Preferences use:

```
saveToSharedPreference("myValue");
```

and to load them all use:

```
loadData();
```

**The Map Interface**

A Map is an object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys: Each key can map to at most one value. [read more...](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

SharedPreferences: [Class Overview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Thanks for prompt help karim I would like to attempt your method but can you tell me what this mean Map<String,?> I didn't get much about this till yet..

Answer (score 1):

Do like this -

1) save in shared preference like this -

```
private void saveToSharedPreference(){
    sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("todoPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPre.edit();
    String myKey = "key";                        // removed +a
    String myValue = et.getText().toString();
    editor.putString(myKey,myValue);
//        editor.putInt("totalTask", a);
    editor.commit();
}
```

2) load it like this -

```
 private void loadData() {
       sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("todoPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       int p = 1;
       String myKey = "key";  // removed "+p"
        String value = sharedPre.getString(myKey, ""); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare with != null in while loop. Use below code and see if the problem solves:-

```
private  void loadData(){
    sharedPre = getSharedPreferences("todoPref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int p = 1;
    String myKey = "key"+p;
    String value = sharedPre.getString(myKey,""); 
    if(!value.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, sharedPre.getString(myKey,""),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```