# Is there any way to delete shared preference value from our local storage without knowing full name of the key?

Tags: android

I want to delete values from my sharedPreference but I don't know the exact name of my key. Means I want to delete all values using a regex which contains some specific words for e.g. if any key contains world "text" that value should be deleted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310479/how-to-iterate-through-all-keys-of-shared-preferences