# How to migrate SharedPrefs to DefaultSharedPrefs?

Tags: android

I have an issue, i'm refactoring my App written years a go, i've changed the whole Settings activity which first was a simple activity with custom checkboxes and edittexts which was saving data in a custom `SharedPrefs` "settings".

Today i've rewritted the whole Settings by using `root_preferences`, so the old and the new datas are saved in different `SharedPrefs`, old data are in `SharedPrefs` "settings" and the new one in `DefaultSharedPreferences`, another point is that in the old Settings page all the switches values was saved as a string like if the switch was on i was saving "ON" else "OFF" and i would refactor even this by simply settings `SwitchPreferenceCompat` saved value to "ON" / "OFF" to make it simplier.

Which would be the way i should take to "migrate" the `SharedPrefs` from *settings* to `DefaultSharedPrefs`?

As if i'd update the App now to someone it will still read values from SharedPrefs settings and the data set in new Settings page will be useless...

**EDIT:**
After following the @snachmsm raccomandations i've ended up by doing a version check of the application (to check if it's the first run or if it's an old version with old settings activity) by reusing the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30274315/9945307) and them i've just made a function which make the whole preferences migration from old values and old shared prefs to new one.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    checkFirstRun(sharedPreferences);

}

private void checkFirstRun(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
    final String PREFS_NAME = "FirstRun";
    final String PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY = "version_code";
    final int DOESNT_EXIST = -1;

    int currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    int savedVersionCode = prefs.getInt(PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY, DOESNT_EXIST);

    // Check for first run or upgrade
    if (currentVersionCode == savedVersionCode) {
        return;
    } else if (savedVersionCode == DOESNT_EXIST) {
        migratePreferences(sharedPreferences);
    } else if (currentVersionCode > savedVersionCode) {
        // UPGRADE
    }

    // Update the shared preferences with the current version code
    prefs.edit().putInt(PREF_VERSION_CODE_KEY, currentVersionCode).apply();
}

private void migratePreferences(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences) {
    SharedPreferences oldPrefs = getSharedPreferences("settings",MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (oldPrefs.getAll().size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    preferencesEditor.putString("ip", oldPrefs.getString("ip", "10.0.0.51"));
    preferencesEditor.putString("txtArt", oldPrefs.getString("txtArt", "10.0.0.51"));
    preferencesEditor.putString("txtTasti", oldPrefs.getString("txtTasti", "10.0.0.51"));
    preferencesEditor.putString("txtTerm", oldPrefs.getString("txtTerm", "1"));
    preferencesEditor.putString("txtColonne", oldPrefs.getString("txtColonne", "4"));
    preferencesEditor.putString("varianti", String.valueOf(oldPrefs.getInt("varianti", 5)));
    preferencesEditor.putString("turni", String.valueOf(oldPrefs.getInt("turni", 0)));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("sottoTavoli", oldPrefs.getString("sottoTavoli", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("prezzoTasto", oldPrefs.getString("prezzoTasto", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("chiediConto", oldPrefs.getString("chiediConto", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("prossimoTurno", oldPrefs.getString("prossimoTurno", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("prezz", oldPrefs.getString("prezz", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("switchMsg", oldPrefs.getString("switchMsg", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("soloSotto", oldPrefs.getString("soloSotto", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("night", oldPrefs.getString("night", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("tastiLaterali", oldPrefs.getString("tastiLaterali", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("famSwitch", oldPrefs.getString("famSwitch", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("riproponiTurno", oldPrefs.getString("riproponiTurno", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("ricaricatasti", oldPrefs.getString("famSwitch", "OFF").equals("ON"));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("order", oldPrefs.getBoolean("order", false));
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean("fidelity", oldPrefs.getBoolean("order", false));
    preferencesEditor.apply();


    // Deleting all old prefs.
    oldPrefs.edit().clear().apply();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is no simple solution for your case. At least you may introduce some migration method at very beginning of your app start (extended `Application` class?)

At first fetch old `ShardedPreferences` (`"settings"`), then [iterate through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310479/how-to-iterate-through-all-keys-of-shared-preferences) and write values to `DefaultSharedPreferences`, after each [remove key](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#remove(java.lang.String)) or at the end [remove whole old file](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#deleteSharedPreferences(java.lang.String)) (API24+). in this method you can introduce `"ON"`/`"OFF"` -> `boolean` migration for cleaner code (as you made a refactoring)

Comment: i've just made it, the only thing i've skipped it was the iteration as in some cases the values are not all strings, check my question edit, thank you. :)