# Preference summary with current value throug custom EditTextPreference: how to get current value?

Tags: android, widget, sharedpreferences

Inspired by [how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-summary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531427/how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-summary) i created my own EditTextPreference that shows its current value in the PreferenceScreen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:key="preferences" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="First Category"
        android:key="first_category">

        <de.k3b.widgets.EditTextPreferenceWithSummary
            android:key="test"
            android:title="Test Message" 
            android:dialogTitle="Test Message"
            android:dialogMessage="Provide a message"   
            android:defaultValue="Default welcome message" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The implementation looks like this

```
package de.k3b.widgets;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.*;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;

public class EditTextPreferenceWithSummary extends EditTextPreference {
    private final static String TAG = EditTextPreferenceWithSummary.class.getName();

    public EditTextPreferenceWithSummary(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public EditTextPreferenceWithSummary(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        Log.e(TAG, "init");
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getContext());     
        String currentText = test prefs.getString("minTrashholdInSecs", this.getText());

// where do i get the current value of the underlaying EditTextPreference ??
//      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        this.setSummary(this.getText());
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Log.w(TAG, "display score changed to "+newValue);
                preference.setSummary(newValue.toString()); // getSummary());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When the PreferenceScreen is first shown there is no current value displayed.

My problem: **Where do i get the current value that the EditTextPreference represents?**
getText() does not get the value as i expected.
After changing the preferencevalue this value is shown in the summary field as expected.

Im am using android 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the following code to your `EditTextPreferenceWithSummary` class:

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    this.setSummary(this.getText());
    return super.onCreateView(parent);
}
```

As for me, it works.
I think the problem was that you were trying to change the UI state out of UI thread (in fact in the constructor).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more complete example, that includes when the value updates, without having to install preference listeners.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class EditTextPreferenceWithValueSummary extends EditTextPreference{

  public EditTextPreferenceWithValueSummary(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public EditTextPreferenceWithValueSummary(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

  @Override
  protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
      this.setSummary(this.getText());
      return super.onCreateView(parent);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
      super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

      if (positiveResult) {
        this.setSummary(getText());
      }
  }
}
```

And in your `xml/settings.xml`:

```
<your.package.views.EditTextPreferenceWithValueSummary
        android:key="some_preference_key"
        android:title="Some Title" />
```

Comment: +1 Indeed this soulution is more elegant than mine. @Oleg Flores got the accepted answer because that solved my issue in 2012.