# How to get textual entries from Android SharedPreference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-settings

I want to retrieve the names of classes as V, VI, VII from the preferences, however, I am getting them in the format 5,6,7 when I try to fetch it.

Values are stored as follows

```
<string name="pref_standard">Standard</string>
<string-array name="pref_standard_list_titles">
    <item>V</item>
    <item>VI</item>
    <item>VII</item>
    <item>VIII</item>
    <item>IX</item>
    <item>X</item>
    <item>XI</item>
    <item>XII</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="pref_standard_list_values">
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
</string-array>
```

The preference is declared as

```
<ListPreference
  android:key="standards_list"
  android:title="@string/pref_standard"
  android:defaultValue="10"
  android:entries="@array/pref_standard_list_titles"
  android:entryValues="@array/pref_standard_list_values"
  android:negativeButtonText="@null"
  android:positiveButtonText="@null"/>
```

I call the value using this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
String standard_name=sharedPref.getString("standards_list","");
```

This gives only the numeric values which are in "pref_standard_list_values".

How to get the textual values which are in "pref_standard_list_titles"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the line

```
android:entryValues="@array/pref_standard_list_values"
```

If you want to translate values in code, use

```
String[] texts = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pref_standard_list_titles);
String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pref_standard_list_values);
```

And lookup the index of `standard_name` in `values`, and its text at that index in `texts`

Comment: This does not work. and I want both value and title in the program. So, I can't use it even if this solution works.

Comment: If you just want it to set the preference directly to the values VII, VIII, then this does work. If that's not what you are trying to do, then I don't understand your question. Maybe you just need to translate the values in code.

Comment: yes, if I set the preference values as VII, VIII, it does work. But it defeats the purpose of having both formats declared together. In SettingsActivity, the textual names can be retrieved using `int index=findPreference("standards_list").findIndexOfValue(stringValue);` `findPreference("standards_list").getEntries()[index]` but the same thing does not work in normal activity.

Comment: OK, I understand the question now. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

To get entries try this:

```
String key = "standards_list";
Preference pref = findPreference(key);
if (pref instanceof ListPreference) {
    ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) pref;
    CharSequence standard_name = listPref.getEntry(); // get currently saved into SharedPreferences single entry value
    CharSequence[] standard_values = listPref.getEntries(); // get all entry values
}
```

For more use cases read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531427/how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-su).

Answer (score 0):

To get name of current selected entry value, use this:

```
  public StringBuilder getSelectedStandardListItem() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append('\n');
    String current_standard_list_item = prefs.getString("pref_standard_list_values", "");
    String[] standard_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pref_standard_list_titles);
    String[] standard_list_value = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pref_standard_list_values);

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (current_standard_list_item.equals(standard_list_value[i])) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    stringBuilder.append(standard_list[0]);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    stringBuilder.append(standard_list[1]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    stringBuilder.append(standard_list[2]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    stringBuilder.append(standard_list[3]);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    stringBuilder.append(standard_list[4]);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    stringBuilder.append(standard_list[5]);
                    break;                       
                case 6:
                    stringBuilder.append(standard_list[6]);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    stringBuilder.append(standard_list[7]);
                    break;              
            }
        }

    }
    return stringBuilder;
}
```

or, to get Entry name by value:

```
    public StringBuilder getEntryNameByValue(String value) {
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append('\n');
String[] standard_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pref_standard_list_titles);
String[] standard_list_value = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pref_standard_list_values);

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (value.equals(standard_list_value[i])) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                stringBuilder.append(standard_list[0]);
                break;
            case 1:
                stringBuilder.append(standard_list[1]);
                break;
            case 2:
                stringBuilder.append(standard_list[2]);
                break;
            case 3:
                stringBuilder.append(standard_list[3]);
                break;
            case 4:
                stringBuilder.append(standard_list[4]);
                break;
            case 5:
                stringBuilder.append(standard_list[5]);
                break;                       
            case 6:
                stringBuilder.append(standard_list[6]);
                break;
            case 7:
                stringBuilder.append(standard_list[7]);
                break;              
        }
    }
}
return stringBuilder;
```

}