# Update EditTextPreference Summary on Post SyncTask

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

In my app once user provide three inputs, `AsyncTask` starts which connects to the server and gets info for two more fields. Once `AsyncTask` is finished, I want to set those two received values in opened setting page.

I searched and try this code, but not updating summary for fields for which value has fetched from server.

Problem is I'm not able to set values received from server as summary to `EditTextPreference`. If I reopen settngs page it shows value not without reopening.

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    updatePreference(key);
}

private void updatePreference(String key) {
    if (key.equals("id")) {
        Preference preference = findPreference(key);
        if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) preference;
            if (editTextPreference.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                editTextPreference.setSummary(editTextPreference.getText());   
            } else {
                editTextPreference.setSummary("");
            }
        }

    } else if (key.equals("sclass")) {
        Preference preference = findPreference(key);
        if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) preference;
            if (editTextPreference.getText().trim().length() > 0) {
                editTextPreference.setSummary(editTextPreference.getText());
                                    } else {
                editTextPreference.setSummary("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean does that gets update if you close the app and reopen or does it  never update?

Comment: gets updated summary in edittextpreference if I reopen setting page.

Comment: so you want to display the changes without reopening ? right?

Comment: yes, I want to update summary so that user can see result. is it possible?

Comment: of course show me where your listener is if my answer didn't work for you.

Comment: have you used `sharedPrefYourObj.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display the current value of an Android Preference in the Preference summary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531427/how-do-i-display-the-current-value-of-an-android-preference-in-the-preference-su)

Comment: solution worked

Comment: if it helps you can accept my answer :)) anyway glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Create a listener and call it in your `onCreate`

```
sharedPrefYourObj.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(t‌​his);
```

try to register you listener `onResume` and unregister it `onPause` though rather than `onCreate`!

example :

```
  protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: I applied listener as per your guidance, It was already on resume but I added for pause as u suggested to unregister. Solution did not work.

Comment: @Panache  do you have a listener in your onCreate

Comment: public class FinalSettings extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

Comment: do I still need to add it oncreate?

Comment: @Panache you only implements the methods in that way.. you need to listen changes ..add a listener like this in your oncreate and see `SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences();
       sharedPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);`

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.preference.PreferenceScreen.getSharedPreferences()' on a null object reference. Got this error after adding your line in oncreate.